# C# OData: get a OData result is very slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, odata

I have that Action:

```
[EnableQuery]
 public IHttpActionResult Get()
 {
     var ordWeb = orderCtx.ORDER.AsQueryable();
     var ordWebDTO =ordWeb.ProjectTo<ORDER>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
     return Ok(ordWebDTO.toList);
 }
```

This an action inside a controller.

`orderWebDTO` is a result of a mapping with some fields coming from different tables of a Database.

In that case `Odata` query coming from Url should be processed AFTER "return" call.

when I use `Odata` Query in the URL (ex. localhost/Controller?%24top=30) EntityFramework load all data from database WITHOUT filter them (in the example: last 30 records).

It's very expensive: I have more than 35k records, and it load all of them and AFTER get last 30...

How can resolve it?

*UPDATE 09.13.18*

I have that kind of mapping with one value calculated while mapping work.

```
var c = new MapperConfiguration(
              cfg => cfg.CreateMap<ORDER, ORDER_WEB>()
                .ForMember(....)
                .ReverseMap()
              );
            mapper = c.CreateMapper();
```

In the `ORDER_WEB` model I have that:

```
public class ORDER_WEB
{
        ...
        ...

        public string ValueFromEntityFrameworkModel  {get; set;}

        public string Set_ORDER
        {
            get
            {
                ORDER_TYPE tipo = new ORDER_TYPE();
                return tipo.GetData(ValueFromEntityFrameworkModel);
            }
            set { }
}
```

without `toList()` It cannot work... 
For this reason OData work on ALL records and AFTER assign the values mapping including `Set_ORDER`.

The point is that : is it possible to do an OData query   (with attributes/parameters) with few records and AFTER assign values mapping?

I hope to be clear...

Answer (score 1):

There are errors in your code sample, but if this accurately reflects what you are doing in your actual code sample, then

```
ordWebDTO.ToList()
```

Will go to the database and retrieve all 35k records AND THEN apply the OData filters you were looking to apply. Compare that to:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<ORDER> Get()
{
    var ordWeb = orderCtx.ORDER.AsQueryable();
    var ordWebDTOs =ordWeb.ProjectTo<ORDER>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
    return ordWebDTOs;
}
```

This will return an IQueryable against which the OData filters will be applied so that when the list is materialized, it is an efficient query to the database.

Comment: thanks a lot @CPerson. However I forget to specify that, in the mapping, I have a value calculated "on-fly" during mapping. In other words it cannot work without toList() method.